# Wrap divs around a central div with CSS

Tags: html, css

Ok, this seems like a silly question, but I still can't find answer elsewhere. I have a bunch of DIVs and I'd like the last (or first, if needed) to be placed in the middle of the screen and wrapped by the rest. Ideally only using CSS.

For example:

```
div div div div div
div div div div div
div  +-----+    div
div  | div |    div
div  +-----+    div
div div div div div
div div div div div
```

I have been able to do this using the following, but the central div is on top of the rest, not wrapped around:

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -11em;
margin-left: -19em;
```

Update: Here is a little bit closer to actual HTML code.

```
<div class="link">link</div>
<div class="link">link</div>
<div class="link">link</div>
<div class="link">link</div>
<div class="link">link</div>
<div class="link">link</div>
<div class="link">link</div>
<div class="link">link</div>

<div class="hero">hero image</div>
```

**Update:** Since the width of each link may vary, some row may have 5 links, and some 3, therefore no strict grid and thus I can't order the elements needed for flexbox. From the responses, while I still don't know if using flexbot can solve this problem, I do have the ability to change my code to the following, if it will help.

```
<div class="hero">hero image</div>
<p class="links">link1 link2 link3 link4 link5 link6 ... </p>
```

I'm wondering if I can center the hero div on the page and have the `<p>` element wrap its content around it.

Comment: Looks like a grid to me, is it? ... We also need a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue.

Comment: I'm using rails and bootstrap, so I have a grid. All the other normal divs get posted to the view first, then the one I want centered comes last. I could adjust the controller, but I'd rather not adjust logic for display.

Comment: Since `position: fixed` won't tell the rest of the `div`'s to make space for the centered one, `flexbox` can reorder an element using its `order` property. Would this be helpful: https://jsfiddle.net/5mtghgx5/

Comment: as @LGSon mentioned display: flex and then changing the order of the divs may work https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Something like [Magazine-like Layout for the Web with CSS Regions and Exclusions](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/regions/adobe/)?